# Catching async errors from eval using domain

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to catch async errors with the npm `eval` module. It's very similar to the normal eval, except it utilizes node's `vm` module directly.

I just came across node's `domain` module. It allows me to catch async errors that occur within `_eval`.

However I checked the documentation and I can't find a `done` event for domain. How am I supposed to know when to resolve the promise?

```
var code = [
  "setTimeout(function () {",
  "  throw new Error('async error sim')",
  "}, 1000)"
].join('\n')

var domain = require('domain')
var _eval = require('eval')
var main = {}

var evalAsync = main.evalAsync = function (code, file) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var d = domain.create();
    d.on('error', function (e) {
      return reject(e)
    })
    var op = d.run(function () {
      return _eval(code, file, {}, true)
    })
    // return resolve(op)
  })
}

evalAsync(code, 'hi.js', {}, true)
  .catch(function (e) {
    console.log(e)
  })
```

Is there a way I can make the `evalAsync` module catch errors and return values correctly?

I've also tried this:

```
var op = d.run(function () {
  return _eval(code, file, {}, true)
})
return resolve(op)
```

Comment: The process exits out when the async code within the domain is finished. It doesn't hang forever. I'm so confused how I can have a handler for when the `d.run` code is finished..

Comment: Domains only catch uncaught exceptions. They don't care about result values.