# Create handler for asynchronous code

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, synchronous

I'm trying to create an async version of eval and I'm looking for a method of converting or wrapping an async operation that doesn't supply it's own callback.

Each one of the these lines runs some time-consuming operation that doesn't have a handler for when it's done.

```
var fs = require('fs')
setTimeout(function () { throw new Error ('hi') }, 3000)
setTimeout(function () { return 'hi' }, 3000)
eval("setTimeout(function () { throw new Error ('hi') }, 3000)")
fs.readFileSync('./package.json', 'utf8')
```

I know that `fs` has a "async" counterpart `fs.readFile`, however for this example I'm interested in how I'd convert the sync version to async.

How would I craft a way of wrapping one of these operations?

I got really close to doing this using the `domain` module.

The normal `try / catch` wont cut it because the code is asyncronous.

```
try {
  setTimeout(function () { throw new Error ('hi') }, 3000)
} catch (e) {
  // no error
}
```

However you can use `domain` to catch the error, like this.

```
var domain = require('domain')
var d = domain.create();
d.on('error', function (e) {
  return reject(e)
})
d.run(function () {
  setTimeout(function () { throw new Error ('hi') }, 3000)
})
```

However there's no way to know if the function is finished running and there is no error.

There's talk in the node community of [deprecating `domain`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/66) and replacing it with [`async_wrap`](http://blog.trevnorris.com/2015/02/asyncwrap-tutorial-introduction.html) but I can't get that to work either.

I'm looking for a way to convert sync to async (synchronous to asynchronous). Or more like async to async with handler.

Both `bluebird` and `async` have ways of converting sync code to async, but not async code to async with handler.

```
var _eval = require('eval')
var async = require('async')
var Promise = require('bluebird')
var _evalCallback = async.wrapSync(_eval)
var _evalPromise = Promise.method(_eval)

var code = [
  'setTimeout(function () {',
  '  throw "hello"',
  '}, 3000)'
].join('\n')

_evalCallback(code, "hi.js", {}, true, function () {
  console.log(arguments) // => { '0': null, '1': {} }
})

_evalPromise(code, "hi.js", {}, true)
  .then(function () {
    console.log(arguments) // => { '0': {} }
  })
  .catch(function () {
    console.log(arguments)
  })
```

Comment: Ever heard of Promises?

Comment: You might want to explain what you are actually trying to achieve. You cannot run two synchronous operations in parallel, at least not like this (i.e. with `fs.readFileSync` with an example). Expand your question to match your actual problem and explain your goal more.

Comment: @Tomalak I'm trying to catch async errors within eval

Comment: @marekful That's exactly what I'm trying to create here

Comment: It is really not clear what you're trying to do here and why. I think you should elaborate on this a bit more like @Tomalak suggested. With Promises, you can execute multiple operations asynchronously in parallel while being able to catch any errors.

Comment: [Here's a like to a more specific version of the question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32195121/catching-async-errors-from-eval-using-domain) 

When you eval code that is async it does not catch the errors. I'd like to create an async version of eval (or any other async operation without a handler) so the function has a callback. Then I can ultimately convert it to a promise.

Comment: @ThomasReggi So you basically want to have inter-context communication, which defeats the purpose of having two separate execution contexts in the first place. I'm not sure if what you want is possible.

Comment: @Tomalak You can think about it that way, or I just want to evaluate a string and catch the error, and if it happens to be async I'd like to still catch the error. It's possible by spinning up a child process :(

Comment: you can always catch unhandled exception, since you obviously plan to eval anything, you could get away with that as well ;)

Comment: @webduvet you mean `process.on('uncaughtException')`?

Comment: @ThomasReggi yes, that's the one